# XML Serialization to use empty array instead of NULL

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I have a property

```
 [XmlElement]
 public string[] Emails { get; set; }
```

which is initialized as string[0] at constructor.

If I XML serialize and deserialize a default instance of this object, the property is NULL.

How can I tell the XML Serializer to use an empty array instead of NULL for this property?

Comment: You can always implement the `{get; set;}` so if `null` is ever set (or attempts to return `null` in the getter) it instead uses an empty array. EDIT: Just be sure if you do the check on the `get` to also store the empty array in the backing field rather than just returning a new instance.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: I have hundred of such properties, is there a way without manual properties?

Comment: Not that I know of. You can create a separate utility class that will (likely via reflection) find all arrays (and collections?) that are `null` and set them to a new instance of their appropriate empty collection. Have it run through this utility when calling your central deserialization method.

Answer (score 8):

5 years later... :)
Replacing Array with List<> did the trick for me.

```
[XmlElement (IsNullable = false)]
public List<string> Emails {get;set;}
```